# Different Images as popup in R at different locations

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I want to have different images at different locations on map as popup with a fixed size. The data is stored in csv file with image name, path of image and latitudes and longitudes and other data.

I tried getting one image as popup and other data as popup.But that photo is shown as popup on all markers and not only on that location with which it is associated.

below code is reading the link that is created as a drive link for all image as:

```
rara <- c('http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/jaltarang/converted/1549597404635.png')
```

rara is the variable name.

below code to have that image as popup:

```
popup=paste("<div class='leaflet-popup-scrolled' style='max-width:600px;max-height:100px',
            "<img src = ", rara , ">"),
```

The expected result is to get images associated with the proper location as popup.Also, there are 4 photos associated with one location so i expect the output to be in 4 links and on clicking those links the image is displayed in different popups.

The actual result which i am getting is that one image is being displayed as popup on all markers instead of only on that marker with which it is associated on the basis of latitudes and longitudes.

Comment: This looks interesting and is most likely feasible. Can you make a minimal working example? It really helps if your question has a very small, working example that somebody can copy into the R instance without having to come up with their own shiny app.